# Must be one or more of "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions..."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I've had this line in my code for a while now:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

I recently updated to `compileSDKversion 23`, and after that I started getting this error:

> Must be one or more of 'getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions...

And then it gives me a list of the possible options.

Does this mean anything bad will happen in my code? Have I done something wrong? Is there any fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

You are using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport; you need to use the right `ActionBar` import for that to work.